# Pandas: PeriodIndex with year starts anchored offset

Tags: python, pandas

**I am having trouble creating a pandas PeriodIndex with anchored offset referencing a year starts month**

Creating a PeriodIndex with a year end month works fine:

```
>>> per_ind = pd.PeriodIndex(start='2001-01-01', periods=1, freq='A-AUG')
>>> per_ind.start_time
DatetimeIndex(['2000-09-01'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
>>> per_ind.end_time
DatetimeIndex(['2001-08-31'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
>>> per_ind.year
Int64Index([2001], dtype='int64')
```

so we get a one year period ending at the end of August 2001. This has year equal to 2001

What I would like to do is create a period that begins in August 2001, ends a year later and has year equal to 2001 (if anybody is interested, this is due to how crop years are reported by USDA; the 2001 crop year for US corn runs from 2001-09-01:2002-08-31 for example)

I would have presumed this was as simple as changing the freq argument to 'AS_AUG', however:

```
>>>per_ind = pd.PeriodIndex(start='2001-01-01', periods=1, freq='AS-AUG')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/space/asd/conda/envs/rd/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/tseries/frequencies.py", line 744, in _period_str_to_code
    return _period_code_map[freqstr]
KeyError: 'AS-AUG'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/space/asd/conda/envs/rd/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2862, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-28-fc801b3bbb96>", line 1, in <module>
    per_ind = pd.PeriodIndex(start='2001-01-01', periods=1, freq='AS-AUG')
  File "/space/asd/conda/envs/rd/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/period.py", line 236, in __new__
    freq, kwargs)
  File "/space/asd/conda/envs/rd/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/period.py", line 288, in _generate_range
    subarr, freq = _get_ordinal_range(start, end, periods, freq)
  File "/space/asd/conda/envs/rd/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/period.py", line 1065, in _get_ordinal_range
    _, mult = _gfc(freq)
  File "/space/asd/conda/envs/rd/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/tseries/frequencies.py", line 335, in get_freq_code
    code = _period_str_to_code(freqstr[0])
  File "/space/asd/conda/envs/rd/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/tseries/frequencies.py", line 746, in _period_str_to_code
    raise ValueError(_INVALID_FREQ_ERROR.format(freqstr))
ValueError: Invalid frequency: AS-AUG
```

Is anybody able to offer any guidance here? I can add an attribute called crop_year to the PeriodIndex but this is very hacky and there should be a neater way of resolving this

EDIT:

This issue arises in pandas Period objects - these cannot be passed any period-start frequencies. Is there a good reason for this?

Comment: You cannot. A PeriodIndex must have ordered values, so it just does't make sense to have a period defined as  `2018-09-01 : 2018-08-31`, but references `2018-09-01 : 2019-08-31` If that were possible, how would you know which dates you were actually using? Create another label column `crop_year`

Comment: One option is to create another date (say `date2`) where you subtract 1 from the year of anything between January 1 and August 31. If you then use `date2` as your date, everything will be shifted to the crop calendar

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the un-ordered values comment. I am requesting ordered values, just that the reference year be assigned to the year in which the period starts, not finishes. Is there any reason why I can't pass a year start anchored offset to the freq argument?